# How keep keys in aerospike effectively?

Tags: java, aerospike

For not very big amount of data we store all keys in one bin with List.

But there are limitations on the size of bin.

Function `scanAll` with ScanCallback in Java client, actually works very slowly, so we cannot afford it in our project. Aerospike works fast when you give him the Key.

Now we have some sets where are a lot of records and keys. What is the best way to store all keys, or maybe there are some way to get it fast and without scanAll ?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand, would this help: http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/Policy.html#sendKey

Comment: @kporter, I have already them. But the problem is to get them quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanning small sets is currently an inefficient operation, because there are 4K logical partitions, and a scan thread has to reduce each of those partitions during the scan. Small sets don't necessarily have records in all the partitions, so you're paying for the overhead of scanning those regardless. This is likely to change in future versions, but is the case for now.

There are two ways to get all the records in a set faster:

1. If you actually know what the key space is like, you can iterate over batch-reads to fetch them (which can also be done in parallel). Trying to access a non-existent key in a batch-read does not cause an error, it just comes back with no value in the specific index.
2. Alternatively, you can add a bin that has the set name, and create a secondary index over that bin, then query for all the records `WHERE setname=XYZ`. This will come back much faster than the scan, for a small set.